# Add a decimal after third character for every record with more than 3 characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column that I need to insert a decimal after the third character, for every row where the char_length is > 4

ex. current

```
Name
_______
1234
123
12345
```

desired output

```
Name
_______
123.4
123
123.45
```

So far I am only able to select the records to be updated, but unsure how to insert into the specific index.

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(name) > 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`insert()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_insert) function:

```
select insert(name, 4, 0, '.')
from t1
where char_length(name) > 4;
```

Note that the code should do what you want without the `where` clause.

This inserts a decimal point at the fourth position in the string.

Comment: Perfect! I'm still unclear about how (name, 4, 0, '.') is specifying the correct place. But it does work.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server use function `STUFF()`

```
select STUFF(col_name, 4, 0,'.') from tab_1
where len(col_name) > 4
```